# SQL UNION and MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, union

I'm having multiple select statements involving many tables and Joins. All the select statements have the same Headers. I'm trying to combine all this into a single result set. So which approach is better SQL `UNION` or `MERGE`? 
I know UNION is A+B. So if a column is NULL in Table A and it has a value in TABLE B then UNION will give me two rows right? So if I want to combine all the rows into a single row based on the id should I use MERGE? I have an option to do this in SQL or SSIS.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, VitalName as VitalName FROM TABLE A
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME, VitalReadings as VitalName FROM TABLE B
```

TableA

```
+----+------+-----------+
| ID | Name | VitalName |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | AAA  | HeartRate |
|  2 |      | Systolic  |
|  3 |      | Diastolic |
+----+------+-----------+
```

TableB

```
+----+------+---------------+
| ID | Name | VitalReadings |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 | AAA  | HeartRate     |
|  2 | BBB  | Systolic      |
+----+------+---------------+
```

Expected Result

```
+----+------+---------------+
| ID | Name | VitalName     |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 | AAA  | HeartRate     |
|  2 | BBB  | Systolic      |
|  3 |      | Diastolic     |
+----+------+---------------+
```

Comment: I would union them all together and in an outer query use Row_Number and / or Rank to handle duplicates.  Merge could be used in your case but is not really made for this type of thing.

Comment: The point of union is not to allow duplicates (unlike union all), but on its own it will not get Systolic to look like @shockwave wants

Comment: A `MERGE` is used to combine `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations into a single statement. Since you're just interested in `SELECT`, you should use UNION. However, there's still the question of how you want to handle ID 2, which appears in both tables. Are you trying to combine them together, or take the one that has a `Name` value, or some other business logic?

Answer (score 7):

`UNION` and `MERGE` totally different concepts and both not solves your problem. But can use `FULL JOIN` for making this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID INT,  Name VARCHAR(10), VitalName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
(1,'AAA','HeartRate'),
(2,NULL,'Systolic'),
(3,NULL,'Diastolic')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE ( ID INT,  Name VARCHAR(10), VitalReadings VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
(1,'AAA','HeartRate'),
(2,'BBB','Systolic')


SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    COALESCE(A.Name, B.Name) Name,
    COALESCE(A.VitalName, B.VitalReadings) VitalName
FROM 
    @TableA A 
    FULL JOIN @TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Result:

```
ID          Name       VitalName
----------- ---------- ----------
1           AAA        HeartRate
2           BBB        Systolic
3           NULL       Diastolic
```

Answer (score 5):

`GROUP BY` the `UNION`'s result. Use `MAX()` to return the NAME:

```
select ID, MAX(NAME), VitalName 
from
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, VitalName as VitalName FROM TABLE A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, NAME, VitalReadings as VitalName FROM TABLE B
) dt
group by ID, VitalName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use union and then use select distinct to remove duplicate.

e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, VitalName as VitalName FROM TABLE_A
UNION SELECT ID, NAME, VitalReadings as VitalName FROM TABLE_B) as TABLE_C`